# Doctrine configuration in php file not updated

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a cron job that runs some Symfony console commands. It recently stopped working correctly. Now when I log into my terminal and run the commands myself, it looks like the previous value of variables is kept in some cache and is not refreshed. My doctrine configuration is loaded with a php file.

#### app/config/config.yml (first lines)

```
imports:
    - { resource: database.php }
```

#### app/config/database.php

```
<?php
$container->setParameter('database_driver', 'oci8');
$container->setParameter('database_host', getenv('SQL_SERVER_NAME'));
$container->setParameter('database_port', getenv('SQL_SERVER_PORT'));
$container->setParameter('database_name', getenv('SQL_ORA_SID'));
$container->setParameter('database_user', getenv('SQL_USER'));
$container->setParameter('database_password', getenv('SQL_PASSWORD'));
```

#### console

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception]
  ORA-24415: Missing or null username.


$ echo $SQL_USER
(some correct value)
```

At that point, I can confirm that all the variables are correctly set in the shell environment, and that none of the doctrine commands work. It looks like the configuration values are read from a cache instead of database.php being run each time, and that cache was set at a time when the shell environment was not set properly. So all the values are empty.

The slighest modification of config.yml triggers a rerun of database.php and puts things in order. But executing cache:clear doesn't work.

```
$ touch app/config/config.yml
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a command switch to force a cache refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some issues due to `dev` and `prod` environments. When running the commands add `--env=prod` to the end of each command (if you run on production environment). Otherwise, development environment will be by default.